# Hovering a button moves elements in cards - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, iconbutton

I'm trying to implement a Card with several texts and at the bottom an icon that will allow navigation. Hovering over this button causes all the elements of the Card to move up because of the splash, how can you avoid this?

I've tried reducing the splashradius to one or making it transparent, that doesn't fix the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home : CardIssue(),
    );
  }
}

class CardIssue extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardIssue({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 180,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 20, 32, 5),
                child: Text("Title"),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 0, 32, 0),
                child: Text(
                  "Content content content Content content content Content content content Content content content Content content content Content content content Content content content ",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.east, color: Colors.black),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      // splashRadius: 1,
                      // padding: EdgeInsets.zero
                      // Not working either
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Image before hover:
[image: Image before hover]
Image after hover:
[image: Image after hover]

Answer (score 0):

```
IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.add),splashRadius: 12, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, )
```

You can use like this. splashRadius is not enough alone you need remove padding in icon button